# App Engine as iOS Backend

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, go, google-api

I'm quite new to backend dev, and Google cloud seemed like a good option for hosting a Golang API for an iOS app.

Recently app started requiring that the app should be accessible in a IPv6 only environment, and I was wondering if Google Cloud App Engine can provide me with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a [blog post in 2010](http://googleappengine.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/app-engine-joins-google-over-ipv6.html) the GAE team stated

> The Google over IPv6 program allows ISPs with good connectivity to request IPv6 access for most Google services. In about a week, we'll be adding Google App Engine and the appspot.com domain to this program. This means that all App Engine apps will become accessible over IPv6 to anyone participating in the program!
>
> For most people, this won't require any changes to your code at all. If your App Engine code reads os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"] in Python, or HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() in Java, be aware that this value may be an IPv4 address, like "192.0.2.1", or an IPv6 address, like "2001:db8::1". Now is the time to verify that your code doesn't make any IPv4-specific assumptions, so that your IPv6-ready users will have a seamless transition.